# Member function that takes member function as parameter

Tags: c++, return-type, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I have one class Hunter that has a member function `random_hunt` which returns a `pair<int, int> const` that's supposed to be equivalent to some point (x, y). I'm trying to implement a second member function `test_hunt` which will return the number of tries it takes the `random_hunt` to land on a target point given the target pair, the member function itself, and the class itself.

I have attempted two implementations:

```
class Hunter {
        // 1
    int test_hunt(std::function<pair<int, int> const()> func, pair<int, int>& const target) {
        int tries = 0;
        while (target != func())
            tries++;
        return tries;
    }

        // 2
    int test_hunt(pair<int, int> const (Hunter::* func)(), Hunter& hunter, pair<int, int>& const target) {
        int tries = 0;
        while (target != (hunter.*func)())
            tries++;
        return tries;
    }
};
```

in main:

```
Hunter hunter;

auto fp = std::bind(&Hunter::random_hunt);
std::cout << hunter.test_hunt(fp, r_start_pos) << '\n';

std::cout << hunter.test_hunt(&Hunter::random_hunt, hunter, r_start_pos) << '\n;
```

Neither compile and I'm not sure why. I've looked at previous examples that do something similar using member functions of `void` return type and they seem to work fine. Is it the return type in my case that's making the difference, or have I simply implemented the function incorrectly?

Comment: OT: Returning by constant value (like `std::pair<int, int> const`) is useless. Nothing stops the caller to save a copy that can be modified.

Comment: As for your problem, templates and lamdas is my recommendation. `template<typename F> int test_hunt(F func, ...) { func(...); }` and call like `object1.test_hunt([&object2](...) { object2.random_hunt(...); }, ...)`

Comment: Or even better, come up with a design that doesn't need you to pass a function as argument.

Comment: There is no `random_hunt` in your given code.

Comment: Also  `&const` isn't valid.

Comment: std::pair (and tuple) are intended to be used for either template progamming of for pairs meaningless numbers. In all other cases you should declare a struct (with two values) and return that.  @Someprogrammerdude I disagree, it declares an intent (e.g. returning an encrypted string). The extra line that copies might trigger questions during a code review (just like const_cast would). Code is also about semantics

Comment: questions about a compiler error should include a [mcve] and the compiler error

Comment: `pair<int, int>& const` should be `pair<int, int> const &`, and the functions need to be public.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't understand your comment about the uselessness of returning a const ref. So what if the caller can make a copy and modify that -- your instance won't be modified. In the case of `std::pair<int, int>`, I wouldn't bother, and would just return a value, but if the data structure is more complex, and the caller doesn't need the copy, returning a const ref can result in a significant improvement in performance.

Comment: My comment is about returning a constant object *by value*. Returning a reference to constant object is a different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::bind` you need to pass object pointer as well along with method, like

```
 auto fp = std::bind(&Hunter::random_hunt,&hunter);
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e497309686eb9cae) is compiled code.

Comment: What if I wanted to add an argument to the `random_hunt` function?

Comment: When do you want to specify the argument? Within main or within test_hunt?

Comment: @NathanXu, you can pass argument either while creation function object(with bind) or while using that object. Check example of std::bind https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind